# Ввести 1D Numpy array с клавиатуры и найти произведение всех элементов вектора

Tags: python, numpy

Ввёл значения массива `a = asarray(input())`. Как теперь обратиться к какому-либо элементу? И как перемножить все элементы массива?

Comment: В каком именно месте у вас сложности? Что не получается?

Comment: Нашел как вводить значения. А как теперь перемножить все элементы массива?

Comment: Что вы понимаете под "перемножить все элементы массива"? Приведите пример входных данных в вопросе и то, что вы ожидаете получить на выходе

Comment: Есть массив [1, 2, 3, 4], нужно перемножить его элементы. Т.е. 1*2*3*4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ввёл значения массива a = asarray(input()). Как теперь обратиться к
>   какому-либо элементу?

вы ввели одну **строку**

```
In [337]: a = np.asarray(input())
1 2 3 4

In [338]: a
Out[338]:
array('1 2 3 4',
      dtype='<U7')
```

если вам надо разбить ее на числа:

```
In [341]: a = np.array(input().split()).astype(int)
1 2 3 4

In [342]: a
Out[342]: array([1, 2, 3, 4])

In [343]: a.dtype
Out[343]: dtype('int32')
```

> как перемножить все элементы массива?

```
In [336]: a.prod()
Out[336]: 24
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогло.